# Maps not updating in MacOS (and iOS)

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui, maps, selection

I have a sample project where you select a location from the sidebar and the location will be displayed on the map. You can select any location and the map will update. But as soon as you move the map and then select a different location, the map will not update to the correct location.

```
struct MapLocation: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let latitude, longitude: Double
    
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var mapLocation: [MapLocation] = [
        MapLocation(name: "Denver", latitude: 39.83205, longitude: -105.01680),
        MapLocation(name: "Key West", latitude: 24.55674, longitude: -81.78736),
        MapLocation(name: "Dallas", latitude: 32.93933, longitude: -96.67838),
        MapLocation(name: "Nashville", latitude: 36.28260, longitude: -86.65211)
    ]
    
    let defaultLocation = MapLocation(name: "Nashville", latitude: 36.28260, longitude: -86.65211)
       
    @State private var selectedLocation: MapLocation?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(selection: $selectedLocation) {
                ForEach(mapLocation) { location in
                    NavigationLink(value: location) {
                        Text(location.name)
                    }
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            MapDetailView(location: selectedLocation ?? defaultLocation)
        }
        
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

struct MapDetailView: View {
    var location: MapLocation
    @State private var position: MapCameraPosition = .automatic
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Map(position: $position) {
                Marker(location.name, coordinate: location.coordinate)
            }
            .frame(height: 500)
            
            Text("Selected locaton: \(location.name)")
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: If you do `MapDetailView(location: selectedLocation ?? defaultLocation).id(selectedLocation ?? defaultLocation)` does it behave as you expect?

Comment: Okay, so the problem is your `MapDetailView` is getting reused and retaining its `@State` without that.